# Fullscreen in IE11 shows white screen

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, three.js, webgl, fullscreen

I'm trying to make a three.js webGL application go fullscreen with

```
launchFullscreen(document.documentElement); 

function launchFullscreen(element) {


      if(element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
      } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
      }

 }
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari - however in IE11 it loads to just a white screen. Any clues on how to fix?

Example here http://beek.co/g282/s1139

Comment: works fine in my 64bit IE11

Comment: Thanks. It's been reported to me as a bug and it's doing the same thing on my machine. Looks like it might be a machine specific setting around hardware acceleration.

Comment: It's also fine if you use f11, which I'd use if it was obvious how to get out of fullscreen (press f11 again) but ideally it would do the same as everything else

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `height: 100%; width: 100%;` for `<html>`.